# Can't use htmlText property in Label

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Label.html - here i see a htmlText property, but when I do this

```
myLabel.htmlText = '<p>some value</p>';
```

i get an error that there are no htmlText property

flex 4.6, spark label

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that you've linked to the documentation for the `<mx:Label />`, which is a completely different component than `<s:Label />`. MX component versus a Spark component (or Flex 3 versus Flex 4).

The reason for the difference is that the newer Spark `Label` component is based off of the Flash Text Engine (FTE), a very low level Actionscript text framework.

There is also another text component that is based off of the Text Layout Framework (that further builds upon the FTE), the [RichText](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/RichText.html) component. This doesn't have an `htmlText` property either, but with TLF you have the ability to supply it with HTML like syntax. Check the docs for RichText if you want to go that route.

With `RichText` you can do stuff like this:

```
<s:RichText>Hello <s:span fontWeight="bold">World!</s:span></s:RichText>
```

Finally, if you have some HTML that you got from elsewhere, and don't want to manipulate it you have at least two options:

1. Use the MX version of `Label` and it's `htmlText` property
2. Use the `RichText` component and the static method `TextConverter.importToFlow()` to convert your HTML string into a TLF `TextFlow` object. Once you create the `TextFlow`, you can use the converted `TextFlow` and set it on the `RichText` component's `textFlow` property, see below.

Using the `TextConverter` class to import HTML text into a `TextFlow` object:

```
private var htmlText:String = "<html><body><p>Hi whirld</p></body></html>";
private var flow:TextFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(htmlText, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
myRichTextLabel.textFlow = flow;
```